# Windows 10 night light turns itself on, ignores windows settings, ignores registry. Any way to disable it completely?

Tags: windows-10, nightlight

No idea when the problem started.

Things I've tried:

- Reinstalling drivers.
- Removing registry keys for night light to reset them, reboot.
- Install [flux](https://justgetflux.com) (so far this is working, but not an acceptable solution).
- Turn off optimizations for the applications.
  Reinstall windows.

Windows WILL NOT stop turning all of my windows yellow/orange, and worse yet the hundreds of posts about this issue simply do not help at all.

Also, is there some other way to completely remove this feature from Windows aside from googling and Super User forums that is more effective? Microsoft support is useless.

I need to work and instead I've spent several hours trying to figure this out to no avail, so I'm wondering if there is perhaps some better place or methods of finding solutions to these types of issues because Windows seems to want to break something that prevents me from using the computer as required to do my job at least once a month and the company isn't interested in fixing it at all or helping, they just force you to re-run steps that are provided on forum posts where the issue was never fixed and the post is abandoned.

Comment: Are you able to edit your post to describe what registry changes?  And if you can reverse them?   You may need to back up and reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1200222/configure-windows-creators-update-night-light-via-registry for more Registry help

Comment: Run Settings, enter "night light" in the search field, click the only entry that comes up, and set "Schedule night light" to Off. This should disable it without registry changes. If it doesn't work, your Windows setup has an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure it is not another software that is dimming the lights?
I mean if no windows/registry option works, maybe it is because you are checking the wrong place right?

If you are 100% sure it is the windows setting, you can still change its intensity to "0." on the option panel.
Display >> Night light settings >> Slide intensity to 0.

That’s not really a "deep fix" but at least you won’t be annoyed with that option any more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.. and the worse is that it the night light does not turn off when it is supposed to. In addition, all ways to disable it do not work.
Surely a bug.
However, I fixed it. I entered "Night Light Settings" and set its "Strength" to 15.

Reason for editing the solution: Rewriting without the apostrophe because adding it changes how it is shown.